# Calling pgr_TSP() function from existing cost matrix table

Tags: postgis, postgresql, pgrouting, travelling-salesman

I am trying to call `pgr_TSP()` function like below using my existing table which has source_id, target_id and cost details but I am not able to get the result?

What should be the syntax for same?

```sql
SELECT * FROM pgr_TSP(
    $$select start_vid, end_vid, agg_cost from cost_matrix,
    SELECT ARRAY[35,37],
    directed=>false 
    $$
);
```

```
Error: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "SELECT"
LINE 2:  SELECT ARRAY[35,37],
```

Also, what does following error mean, I got it while using TSP:

```
NOTICE:  pgr_TSP no longer solving with simulated annaeling
HINT:  Ignoring annaeling parameters
```